# How to get average of similar named columns in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data with 12 columns containing balance of 12 months for each customer as shown below, how to create an additional column with average of the 12 months balances (b0 to b11).

| customer | b0 | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 | b6 | b7 | b8 | b9 | b10 | b11 | avg_bal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust_1 | 20 | 30 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 25 |
| cust_2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| cust_3 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 50 | 30 | 10 | 30 |
| cust_4 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |

I want to have a generic code based on column names, Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to have "have a generic code based on column names"? You can always write a function that takes a list of columns and does avg calculation on them. Or do you want to have the code which somehow determines what columns should be averaged? If yes, then that's a whole different set of problems you need to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
df.withColumn("sum", sum(F.coalesce(F.col(col), F.lit(0)) for col in df.schema.names if col!="customer"))\
  .withColumn("count", sum([F.col(col).isNotNull().cast(IntegerType()) for col in df.schema.names if col!="customer"]))\
  .withColumn("avg", F.col("sum") / F.col("count"))\
  .show()
```

Instead of `for col in df.schema.names if col!="customer"`, you can also use `for col in df.schema.names if "b" in col` if you have columns other than `customer` as well. You can use any condition to select the columns to be averaged but the basic idea is the same.

Input:

[image: Input]

Output (You can drop the intermediate columns, I kept them for understanding) :

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I thought we just need to nvl the columns and add them up, then divide by 12. Something like this:
(nvl(b0,0) + nvl(b1,0) + ... nvl(b11,0)))/12

Am I too naive?

Comment: Hey @VietnamDataEngineer, divided by 12 will not work as certain months may have null values which are to be excluded from denominator, so we would need a dynamic method for that